# Phone number form with country code in Laravel 8 x-form.input tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, laravel-8

I already have built form with <x-form.input> tag in laravel 8 and It is working now.
But now need to add a phone number field when users register their account.
This is current code.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('L4.contestants.store', $organization) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="row mb-4 md-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label for="birthdate"> Birthdate </label>
                        <x-form.input type="date" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" />
                    </div>
                </div><!--/row-->

                <div class="row mb-4 md-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label for="phone"> Phone Number </label>
                        <x-form.input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" />
                    </div>
                </div><!--/row-->

                <hr>

                <x-form.buttons submit-name="Add" :cancel-url="route('L4.contestants.index', $organization)" />

            </form>
```

Now it is working but I need to use with country and validation.
We should use x-form tag due to needn't change others.
Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the **[Laravel-Phone package](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone)** as this is, at least in my opinion, the cleanest way to validate and format phone numbers.

```
$request->validate([
    'phone' => [
        'required',
        Rule::phone()->detect()->country('ES'),
    ],
]);
```

To format a phone number, for example to have a consistent form to save to your database or to compare against, use:

```
PhoneNumber::make('666666666', 'ES')->formatE164(); // returns +34666666666
```